# application_start equivalent in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to execute a method to cache a bunch of data as soon as a web api 2.2 app loads.  I think WebForms had something like an Application_Start event in its Global.asax file.  Does Web API 2.2 have any type of equivalent event where I can trigger the method to cache the necessary data?

Comment: ASP.NET Web API runs on ASP.NET. Application_Start is an event of ASP.NET, not of Web Forms. You can use it

Comment: @AndersonPimentel You shouldn't link to Portuguese docs though (note the pt-br in the URL)

Comment: Oh, boy, MS keeps pushing the localized version, no matter what. Deleted and reposting the English one. Thanks.

Comment: @user9393635, check the docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api